# How to list all the TCP_alloc on a server?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, tcp

I run a node_exporter on my server and node_exporter shows that there are over 5K TCP_alloc on the server. After rebooting the server, the count of TCP_alloc is still over 5K.
There are only a few lines when I run the command `netstat -anltup`. Is it the correct ways to list the TCP_alloc? How to list all the TCP_alloc and reduce this value down?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in  /proc/* ;
do
  if [ -d $i/fd ];then
    echo $i   $(ls $i/fd -l | grep socket: |wc -l)
  fi
done
```

To find out all the TCP connections of each process. It's OK now.